# Which template should I choose for create a 'Master View'

Tags: template

I'm just get start with SP2013 for a week, and my boss give me a task. 
My company have 3 SP sites :

my.mycompany.net : (personal site of members in company).....

team.mycompany.net: (team site for each team in our company)....

learn.mycompany.net: (site contain document, videos for employee learning)....

My tasks is: Design 'Master View' to access all these sites through one entry point.

In my opinion, I'll create a site collection, and inside it, I'll create 3 subsite (my,team,learn) and my task done. But, the problem is, I don't know which template should I use. AM I RIGHT? If not, Where should I get start?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to accomplish what you want.

One of them : You first need to create a web application with domain orientsoftware.net 
[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276326%28v=office.15%29.aspx) you have a tutorial how to do it.

Later on you need to create three new site collections. One for my , one for team and one for learn. 
I suggest that for my you use My site host template for my.yourcompany.com, Team Site template for team.yourcompany.com and enterprise wiki for learn.yourcompany.com.

Bear in mind that the domains for the site collections will be of the form orientsoftware.net/sites/my

If you want to have them at the form team.yourcompany.net you have to create three web applications with wanted domain and for each of them create the corresponding site collection.

Comment: Tks for your answer, right row our test server not complete yet, I'll try whenever it done. And I'll ask u if I got any problem :)

Comment: Feel free to ask me

Comment: I've create a web application and 3 site collection like you said. So now, How can I create Master View? Should I directly design my own Master Page in mycompany.net?

Comment: Now I have a web application at : mycompany.net , a site collection at mycompany.net, and three site collections mycompany.net/my   mycompany.net/team   mycompany.net/learn . What should I do next?

Comment: when you created the site collections did you pick the type that I recommended you ?

Comment: yes, mycompany.net I'm using "Publishing portal" . /my I'm using "My Sie Host", /team i'm using "Team Site" , /learn i'm using "Enterprise Wiki".

Comment: now I have those site collections 1 -- mycompany.net(Publishing portal). 2-- mycompany.net/my(My Site Host). 3-- mycompany.net/team(Team Site). 4-- mycompany.net/learn(Enterprise Wiki). So what should I do next ???

Comment: Well it depends in what you want to do. As far as I can understand from your question the problem that you had is already solved and you have three sites that you can access through the same entry points. I suggest you put some links on each of these pages so you can easily access the other pages. Let me know what you are not sure about what to do next.

Comment: I've created a custom master page and aply it to mycompany.net(Publishing portal) by using Design Manager. Is there any ways to three other site collections inherit this custom master page from mycompany.net???

Comment: Export the template from teh master page and then import it to your custom pages

Answer (score -1):

You can use Blank Site template and on the landing page, put the links to the 3 subsites.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer about how this can be achieved?

Comment: how to create site collection using Blank SIte template. there is no template call Blank Site. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262410%28v=office.15%29.aspx